# Dynamically change .mtl of .obj OBJMTLLoader

Tags: three.js, textures

How can I dynamically change material on my .obj model? Each of my model contains .obj, .mtl and .jpg files with textures. Should I change .mtl file somehow?

In the code below I center geometries of each child mesh of my .obj , then I try to give it texture, but neither commented code nor loader.load is not giving it texture.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                object = event.content;
                for (var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++) {
                    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(geometry, object.children[i].geometry);
                }
                THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );
                //var materials = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("/obj/stol.mtl");
                //mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( material ) );

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,  material );

                mesh.scale.x = 0.25;
                mesh.scale.y = 0.25;
                mesh.scale.z = 0.25;
                mesh.castShadow = true;

                scene.add( mesh );
                animate();
            });
            loader.load( '/obj/stol.obj', '/obj/stol.mtl' );
```

I'd like to have some buttons on my page that trigger texture changes onclick, e.g

```
$(function(){
    $('#txt_01').click(function(){
        mesh.textureLoad("/obj/txt_01.mtl");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm looking for a hint not ready code, really no1 can help me?

Comment: Could you share with me ready code @Artur Fidelus?

Answer (score 1):

Just check the examples about loading a texture.

And how to update stuff in three.js , see the "material update" section.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Comment: Those examples use JSON loader, I use obj+mtl.
I managed to use obj+jpg material, but I can't save it properly in 3dmax with "render to texture".
Should I change my loader to match those examples?

Comment: sorry, i don't know what you are doing atm and how your code looks and what you are doing with 3dsMax RTT dialog

Comment: Well, Your link wasn't bad after all, I was able to make material-changing buttons with obj+jpg uvw maps. Link:
http://www.edar.com.pl/test-3d-3/
...but, it's still not the solution I'm looking for, beceause I believe that using .mtl array would be more efficient.

Comment: Could you update the link @GuyGood? I clicked then went there. However, there are nothing in that site.